# Memory usage remains 99 % even after create index is done on MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb

While doing indexing on MongoDB. Now we have nearly 350 GBs of data in the database and its deployed as a windows service in AWS EC2.

And we are doing indexing for some experimentation. But every time I run the indexing command the memory usage goes to 99% and even after the indexing is done the memory usage keeps like that until I restart the service.

The instance has 30 GB of RAM and SSD drive. And right now we have the DB setup as stand alone (not sharded till now). And we are using the latest version of MongoDB.

Any feedback related to this will be helpful.

Thanks,

Arpan

Comment: This is normal, intended behavior. Any memory not used is memory wasted.

Answer (score 6):

That's normal behavior for MongoDB.

MongoDB grabs all the RAM it can get to cache each accessed document as long as possible. When you add an index to a collection, each document needs to be read once to build the index, which causes MongoDB to load each document into RAM. It then keeps them in RAM in case you want to access them later. But MongoDB will not squat the RAM. When another process needs memory, MongoDB will willingly release it.

This is explained in [the FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-lot-of-ram):

> **Does MongoDB require a lot of RAM?**
>
> Not necessarily. It’s certainly
>   possible to run MongoDB on a machine with a small amount of free RAM.
>
> MongoDB automatically uses all free memory on the machine as its
>   cache. System resource monitors show that MongoDB uses a lot of
>   memory, but its usage is dynamic. If another process suddenly needs
>   half the server’s RAM, MongoDB will yield cached memory to the other
>   process.
>
> Technically, the operating system’s virtual memory subsystem manages
>   MongoDB’s memory. This means that MongoDB will use as much free memory
>   as it can, swapping to disk as needed. Deployments with enough memory
>   to fit the application’s working data set in RAM will achieve the best
>   performance.
>
> See also: [FAQ: MongoDB Diagnostics](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/) for answers to additional questions
>   about MongoDB and Memory use.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the info. 
I am very new to MongoDB and we are planing to use our Database as MongoDB. But just thinking as the 99 % of the RAM is taken by Mongo and if that time we do some rapid insertion and fetching will it cause to slow the machine?  

Thanks

Comment: @user3350562 When you create an index for collection A and then access collection B, the content of A might have displaced any cached documents from B, so they all need to be read from hard drive. But that's cache confusion you can hardly avoid in any system which uses caching. The RAM usage itself is not a problem at all, because as I wrote and as the FAQ writes, MongoDB will release RAM when the system needs it for something else. MongoDB will only grab RAM which is currently unused.

Comment: I need some more information from you guys.
We are planning to migrate our Legacy system data (SQL SERVER) to cloud and the datastore we are thinking as Mongo. As of now we have 1 TB of data and currently we have inserted for testing with 350 GB in Mongo, which has nearly 15 millions of documents. 

The db has to be able to serve simultaneous insert and fetch in very rapid rate. Can you guys suggest the best environmental setup for this. Like should we go with windows or linux and so...

Comment: @Arpan When you have any more questions, you are free to [ask them as such](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But most of what you are asking sounds too subjective and opinion-based for stackoverflow.

Comment: I am very new to this MongoDB and as we are currently moving aall our production components to cloud and planning to go from traditional relational RDBMS to NO SQL database. So gathering all required knowledge related to it. and going forward with my testing with MongoDB in cloud with production data. So you can understand.... :)